# Solution to an equation with linear, logarithmic, exponential expression

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I am solving for an expression with a Possion distribution $P(k)=\frac{\mu^k}{k!}e^{-\mu}$ given by
$$\ln \phi_\infty = \lambda \phi_\infty - \mu e^{-\lambda \phi_\infty},$$ where $\lambda, \mu \in [0,1]$ are constant rates and $\phi_\infty= \lim_{t \to \infty} \phi(t)$. The actual derivation of this expression is long and hence I have excluded it from this post.

Is there any solution to this expression? Is it solvable? At the very least, I need to simplify $\phi_\infty$ in such a way that I could substitute it to the expression for late-time epidemic prevalence
$$R_\infty = 1 - e^{-\mu(1-e^{-\lambda \phi_\infty})}.$$

Any help or direction is well appreciated. I do not even need an exact solution only that I need to simplify or estimate $R_\infty$ in terms of the rate parameters $\lambda, \mu$. Thank you!

Note: I have been excluding the derivation of these expressions because they are long. Please let me know if I ever need to elaborate.

Comment: Are you willing to solve $\ln \phi_\infty = \lambda \phi_\infty - \mu e^{-\lambda \phi_\infty},$ for $ \phi_\infty $ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, what do you mean willing? I have tried solving for $\phi_\infty$ but I seem to be going around in circles

Comment: Sorry ! Being blind, some times I misread. So, this is the equation to be solved. Could you provide typical orders of magnitude for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ ? What is the order of magnitude of $\lambda \phi_\infty $ ?

Comment: Please, answer m'y above questions

Comment: This seems to work (have a look at the results in my edit)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I am not sure what the exact order of magnitude is but that its for small values greater than 0.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, can we not have k=1? And is $W(−\frac{k}{e}) \simeq−1$
? I am not sure if I can use the identity $W(−\frac{1}{e})=1$
 for this.

Comment: Have a look at my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is to find an approximate solution of the equation$$\log( \phi_\infty) = \lambda \phi_\infty - \mu e^{-\lambda \phi_\infty}$$

Using $x=\lambda \phi_\infty$, we need to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\mu  e^{-x}-x+\log (x)-\log (\lambda )$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$x_* \qquad \text{such that} \qquad e^{-x_*}=\frac{1-x_*}{\mu \, x_*}$$ which has a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function (this is nice but not very helpful, I am afraid)
$$f(x_*)=\frac{1}{x_*}-x_*+\log (x_*)-(1+\log (\lambda ))$$

However, if $x$ is small, a first approximate solution, obtained by the first term of the expansion of $e^{-x}$, is
$$\color{blue}{x_0=-\frac 1{1+\mu}\,W\left(-\lambda\,(1+\mu)\,  e^{-\mu } \right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is the usual Lambert function; in the real domain, it exists if
$$\lambda\,(1+\mu)\,  e^{-\mu } \leq \frac 1 e$$

I suppose that the first iterate of Newton method
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$ which is fully explicit, could be  quite decent.

Since we need to work in the ral domain, let
$$\lambda=k \,\frac{e^{\mu -1}}{\mu +1}\qquad \text{with}\qquad 0 < k  < 1$$

This makes
$$x_0=-\frac 1{\mu +1}\,W\left(-\frac{k}{e}\right)$$

Computing a few values over a grid $(\mu,k)$, the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \mu & k & x_0 & x_ 1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.06639847 & 0.06636738 &  0.06636739 \\
 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.14613042 & 0.14577152 &  0.14577205 \\
 0.2 & 0.6 & 0.24756955 & 0.24560880 &  0.24561952 \\
 0.2 & 0.8 & 0.39305992 & 0.38340183 &  0.38360615 \\
 0.4 & 0.2 & 0.05691297 & 0.05687371 &  0.05687373 \\
 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.12525464 & 0.12480059 &  0.12480157 \\
 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.21220247 & 0.20972344 &  0.20974312 \\
 0.4 & 0.8 & 0.33690851 & 0.32481213 &  0.32516975 \\
 0.6 & 0.2 & 0.04979885 & 0.04975932 &  0.04975933 \\
 0.6 & 0.4 & 0.10959781 & 0.10913971 &  0.10914086 \\
 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.18567716 & 0.18317385 &  0.18319661 \\
 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.29479494 & 0.28261863 &  0.28302370 \\
 0.8 & 0.2 & 0.04426565 & 0.04422856 &  0.04422858 \\
 0.8 & 0.4 & 0.09742028 & 0.09698979 &  0.09699093 \\
 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.16504637 & 0.16269040 &  0.16271301 \\
 0.8 & 0.8 & 0.26203995 & 0.25058132 &  0.25098062 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

As I wrote above, the first derivative cancels at $x_*$.
If this value exists in the real domain, depending on the sign of
$$f(x_*)=\frac{1}{x_*}-x_*+\log (x_*)-(1+\log (\lambda ))$$ we can have no root, a double root or two roots.

For example , using $\mu=0.1$, $$x_*=0.963238$ \quad \implies \quad f(x_*)=-0.962527 - \log(\lambda)$$

So, if $\lambda < 0.381926$ there is no solution: if $\lambda =0.381926$, there is a double root very close to  $x=1$. Otherwise two solutions : for example, usinf $\lambda=0.2$ the roots are $x_1=0.233331$ and $x_2=2.55542$ while the estimates are
$$-\frac{10}{11} W_0\left(-\frac{11}{50 \sqrt[10]{e}}\right)=0.234125$$ $$-\frac{10}{11} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{11}{50 \sqrt[10]{e}}\right)=2.31851$$

So, we need to know a bit more about the order of magnitude of $\phi_\infty$ to ddecide which branch of Lambert function we need to use.

I give below the value of $\phi_\infty$ which would make $f(x_*)=0$ (the limiting case).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & \phi_\infty \\
 0.1 & 26.5589 \\
 0.2 & 8.68700 \\
 0.3 & 4.07644 \\
 0.4 & 2.29969 \\
 0.5 & 1.48461 \\
 0.6 & 1.05528 \\
 0.7 & 0.80153 \\
 0.8 & 0.63775 \\
 0.9 & 0.52485 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! Might you be able to provide references I could read on about Lambert functions? Particularly how that approximation happened to be.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you came upon the Lambert function? I am not very familiar with this and would like to understand how that entered the analysis (so I can explain it properly as well). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user1178472. Lambert function is a fascinating one. To give you an idea, on the search bar, just type *Lambert* to see $4,282$ entries. On the site, there is a tag `lambert-w`. Have a first look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @user1178472. Expand to first order the exponential to rewrite $$f(x)=\mu(1-x)-x+\log (x)-\log (\lambda )$$  that is to say $$f(x)=(\mu-\log (\lambda ) )-(\mu +1) x+\log (x)=0$$ and then Lambert.

Comment: @user1178472   By the way, if you consider that this is a valid answer, may be you could accept it

Comment: Can we not have k=1? And is $W\bigg(-\frac{k}{e}\bigg) \approx -1$? I am not sure if I can use the identity $W\bigg(-\frac{1}{e}\bigg)=1$ for this.